# SSL 3 is still enabled after setting registry keys and rebooting Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, iis-7.5, tls

I have searched all over and can't seem to find an answer.

I am attempting to disable SSL 3.0 and enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 on my Windows 2008 R2 server using IIS 7.5.

I have made all the registry changes necessary and have rebooted the server multiple times, but ssllabs.com is still reporting SSL3 on with TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 off.

I also used IISCrypto to apply the keys with the same results after reboot.

I have done this on all our other servers with success, but this server will not take the changes.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
James O.

Comment: Can you provide the output of: `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 hostname` . You can download nmap here: https://nmap.org/dist/nmap-7.12-win32.zip

Comment: Your suggestion showed me what the problem is.  This is a Citrix Secure Gateway.  IIS is listening on port 444 whereas the Secure Gateway is listening on port 443.

When I run your command on port 443, I see SSL3 on, but when I run it on port 444, SSL3 is off and TLS1.1 and 1.2 are on.

I guess I need to make some changes in the Citrix software.

Answer (score 1):

Is your site behind a load balancer such that the public facing URL isn't directly going to your IIS box(es)?  If so, you need to make those changes on the load balancer.

Comment: There is no load balancer.  Traffic goes directly to IIS on the server.

Comment: I was wrong.  Apparently traffic is redirected to the Citrix Secure Gateway installed on this server and then to IIS.  See answer below for solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Greg and Ryan.  Your comments made me realize that IIS is not handling incoming traffic directly.  I did not take into consideration that the Citrix Secure Gateway was running on this server.

After following the instructions at http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX201762, SSL3 is now disabled.

Unfortunately, the Secure Gateway does not support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 though.

Thanks,
James O.

Comment: you have to upgrade the SG to get the support for TLS